# go:generate stringer undeclared name: CONST

Tags: go, enums, go-generate

I've used stringer to generate a String() method for different types and have put the output directory to `stringer/`

```
//go:generate -type TYPE -output stringer/TYPE_string.go
```

But stringer doesn't recognize the package and therefore generates

```
var x [1]struct{}
    _ = x[ENUM-0]
```

instead of

```
var x [1]struct{}
    _ = x[model.ENUM-0]
```

Is there any workaround or method that can help me generate the code in a different directory ?